# Subscribe button label

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

In an administration panel, I have a "Subscribe" button, which will send a mail each time a new user registers to the application. What would be a correct way to name the button label?

> 1. Subscribe to new registrations
> 2. Subscribe to registrations
> 3. Subscribe for new registrations
> 4. Registrations subscriptions

Comment: I think *notify* would be much better than *subscribe* here. "Notify about new registrations". Subscription usually implies more content - newsletter, summary, discussions, etc. not just short notices "X has registered".

Comment: thx SF. actually for each new user, we receive a small email, yes I agree it's more a mail "alert" or notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Subscribe* sounds fine to us technical people because it has the same meaning as in the well known *publisher/subscriber* design pattern, but I think a non-technical person would have a hard time knowing what are the implications of this subscription. I would choose *Notify me when new users register*.

This is, by the way, the style of Microsoft Outlook:

> Notify me when new messages arrive

or WordPress:

> Notify me when new comments are added

Comment: Could I use "Notify me for new messages"?
(one word shorter)

Comment: @cyril Better *Notify me of new users*. Though I think what I proposed is clearer.